# custom fonts not loading after upgrading from angular 7 to 8

Tags: angular, fonts

We've just upgraded our angular application from 7 to 8. We have a few custom fonts which we've been loading as follows:

```
 @font-face {
     font-family: "Source Sans Pro Light";
     src: url("/assets/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf"); }


 @font-face {
     font-family: "Source Sans Pro Semibold";
     src: url("/assets/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-SemiBold.ttf");
```

After upgrading to Angular 8 the fonts no longer load. They error out with:

```
GET http://windows2/assets/fonts/Titillium_Web/TitilliumWeb-SemiBold.ttf net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET http://windows2/assets/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET http://windows2/assets/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Please note that this happens only when we build and deploy on an application server. When we serve it using ng serve the fonts load and display just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. using the following solved it for me.

```
@font-face {
     font-family: "Source Sans Pro Light";
     src: url("./assets/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf"); }


@font-face {
     font-family: "Source Sans Pro Semibold";
     src: url("./assets/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-SemiBold.ttf");
```

notice the ./assets instead of /assets

hoping this helps

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the path defined in *CSS* or *SCSS* file,
use **../assets** instead **/assets**

,eg

```
 @font-face {
 font-family: "Source Sans Pro Light";
 src: url("../assets/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf"); }


@font-face {
 font-family: "Source Sans Pro Semibold";
 src: url("../assets/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-SemiBold.ttf");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the above given answers by others are not working. Please try the following. **Use ~/ instead of /**

```
 @font-face {
     font-family: "Source Sans Pro Light";
     src: url("~/assets/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf"); }


 @font-face {`enter code here`
     font-family: "Source Sans Pro Semibold";
     src: url("~/assets/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-SemiBold.ttf");
```